# getchar_unlocked in windows undeclared

Tags: c++, scanf

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void scan(int* i)
{
    int t=0;
    char c;
    bool negative=false;
    c=getchar_unlocked();
    while(c<'0'&&c>'9')
    {
        if(c=='-')
            negative=true;
        c=getchar_unlocked();
    }
    while(c>'0'&&c<'9')
    {
        t=(t<<3)+(t<<1)+c-'0';
        c=getchar_unlocked();
    }
    if(negative)
        t=~(t-1); //negative
    *i=t;
}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    int i;
    scan(&i);
    return 0;
}
```

I know that the function defined here as `scan` is faster than `scanf` and is very useful on programming competitions. But for some reason this code is not working on Windows and is working on Linux. What do I do to get it working on Windows? I am using the `g++` compiler from Dev-C++.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`getchar_unlocked` is not a C or C++ standard function and therefore it's no surprise that it doesn't work on Windows. It is a POSIX standard I think, but Windows compilers don't support all POSIX functions.

If you replaced `getchar_unlocked` with `getchar`, it would kind of work, although the algorithm doesn't seem quite right.

You could do this with conditional compilation, like this for instance

```
#ifdef _WINDOWS
// no getchar_unlocked on Windows so just call getchar
inline int getchar_unlocked() { return getchar(); }
#endif
```

Comment: is there a way I can determine whether `getchar_unlocked` is defined in the target system?

Comment: If you know which systems it is defined on you can use conditional compilation. But I don't know of any totally automatic way to do this.

Answer (score 3):

Windows have the equivalent, _getchar_nolock, it is Windows specific.

See this link:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4y2e9z0c.aspx

So if you are  happy with a non-threadsafe version and you want the best possible performance you could do something like this:

```
#ifdef WIN32
// no getchar_unlocked on Windows so call _getchar_nolock
inline int getchar_unlocked() { return _getchar_nolock(); }
#endif
```

Answer (score 0):

`getchar_unlocked()` is mainly used for competitive programming, however, if you want to use this elsewhere, just make sure, only 1 thread is using it at a time.
Same applies to putchar_unlocked() function too.
It is a POSIX equivalent so Windows compiler doesn't support it.
However, you can use either of two-

1. Normal speed

   int getchar_unlocked() { return getchar(); }
   void putchar_unlocked(char _c) { putchar(_c); }
2. Fast speed

   int getchar_unlocked() { return _getchar_nolock(); }
   void putchar_unlocked(char _c) { _putchar_nolock(_c); }