# Can't use getchar_unlocked with code::blocks + MingW on windows 7 64 bit

Tags: c++, windows, codeblocks

I can run my code on online compilers like ideone.com just fine. But MinGW gives the error -

```
error: 'getchar_unlocked' was not declared in this scope
```

Is there a workaround for this?
My OS is Windows 7 Ultimate 64bit.

Comment: Code::Blocks is not a compiler. It is an IDE. What is the actual compiler you're using within Code::Blocks? Second, did you `#include` the appropriate header file?

Comment: MinGW, what else?
and, <cstdio>.

Comment: I found this -
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13010505/getchar-unlocked-in-windows-undeclared
stating Windows has getchar_unlocked undeclared.

Comment: The answer is the same as it is to this thread-

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13010505/getchar-unlocked-in-windows-undeclared

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is the same as it is to this thread-

[getchar_unlocked in windows undeclared](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13010505/getchar-unlocked-in-windows-undeclared)

Not all POSIX functions are declared in Windows. And since getchar_unlocked is considered a multithreading-unsafe function, it is understandable why it has been left undeclared in Windows.

I have found that it works perfectly well in Linux (at least in Ubuntu 12.04).

Comment: i have found that it shows the same error in ubuntu 14.04 , any help about that ?

Comment: @BhawinParkeria check if you have c++ compiler installed. Run sudo apt-get build-essential and then try your code by compiling with g++